# How to prevent a resistor receiving a too high power?

Tags: resistors, ohms-law

If a circuit was creating 0.3 watts, and resistors rated for 1/4 watts were used, what would be the easiest way to make it stay inside the rating? Would it be to, say, connect two resistors of twice the resistance in parallel, thereby cutting the watts applied to each in half?

Also, I've experienced that when connecting a 1/4 watt resistor of approx. 50 ohms in series with a 10V supply, it gets hot and its resistance increases a LOT (To a couple of kilo-ohms). Is this normal, and shouldn't the resistance stay the same within the limitation?

Comment: While I appreciate you accepting my answer, it's a good idea to wait a while for others to have a chance to answer or after a few answers have collected.  Others will now probably skip this question seeing it is already answered, and you'll never know what they might have said.  Of course my answer is totally correct and to the point and there is nothing for others to add :-)

Comment: Very humble of you, and I usually use that approach, but your answer gave me all the information I was seeking, so it's all good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use multiple resistors in various combinations of parallel and series to get higher dissipation.  However, consider the heat coupling between the multiple resistors.  If a significant portion of the heat from one resistor gets to another, the total dissipation of that resistor will have be less to stay in spec.

Do the math.  10 volts accross a 50 Ω resistor causes **2 watts** of dissipation.  How can you possibly expect a resistor to adhere to any of its specs when you violated its maximum dissipation, in this case by a factor of 8 no less!?

As soon as you violate any spec in the datasheet, the manufacturer no longer promises any of the other specs will be adhered to.  If you violate a absolute maximum spec, the part can be irreversibly damaged.  It can fail other specs later in subtle ways, or it can catch fire or vanish into a greasy black mushroom clould without notice.

Comment: Ah, I see I failed completely in calculating the watts, now realizing that I had to square the volts..

Comment: Sorry, another question while we're at it: If a 5% error carbon resistor is used rather than a metal film one with a 1% error, and the error of a carbon resistor is measured to 1.01Kohms, can you expect it to stay at that value, or might it vary during use, after production? (I'm thinking it's a 5% error only from production)

Comment: @DLA: The "5%" error figure when not specifically qualified means that is the maximum error from the nominal value over the full range of the other operating conditions.  There is more to it than simply the initial error, like aging and temperature drift.  Sometimes these are specified separately, so you can work backwards and figure the maximum contribution to the overall error from initial value error.

Comment: 5% from production. When a carbon resistor is operated close to its rated power for 30 years, its resistance can increase by 50% or so - as you can see if you get a valve amplifier to repair...